# Maven project failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have developed one maven project that uses `pom.xml` to resolve dependencies,it is build success in my IntelliJIDEA but it's showing build errors in my friend's IntelliJIDEA.

It says

> failed to read artifact descriptor for...

If I copy my local repository to his system and build,it is built success. Please, suggest the possible cause and solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably referencing libraries that are not public / do only exist on your system.

if your project consists of multiple maven artefacts - try mvn install on each of them individually if you are not using a parent/reactor file

Comment: I am using one parent file that is on some remote system and i am getting the libraries of the parent file through maven... I tried mvn install separately for each artifact but problem is not resolved.

Comment: which artifact is it complaining about? is it one of your artifacts or an external one? Did you supply the correct version everywhere?

Comment: it is complaining about one of the external artifacts. I supplied the correct version everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a repository URL to your .m2/settings.xml file.  If you are able to reach the public repositories from your workplace then you can use one of the big ones out there, just google for them.  If you can't reach them in your workplace, it may be worthwhile to set up your own mirror with something like Artifactory, then your IT might be willing to allow that one server to have the access needed to mirror the public repositories.

Update:  Since I can't leave comments on other folks questions and answers yet:

Can you provide the pom.xml contents and tell us which dependency is causing the error?  I can create a test project and add it, and see if it is trying to download other dependencies too, since I have an Artifactory instance that mirrors the public sites.  Then if that is the problem, I can tell you which of those to add to your pom and add with maven install.

Oh, didn't notice that the comments are from '14.  Sheesh, sorry about that.  Well, if you are still having any problems feel free to update!

Comment: anyway...thanks for answering...this was an artifactory issue